# Sql Server query works in management studio but not in C# (ServiceStack.OrmLite)

Tags: sql-server, recursion, servicestack

The following recursive query works in SSMS, but not in a C# query in ServiceStack. It boils down to the query (I think)... or the fact that I'm using OrmLite... in SQL Server Management Studio the query works pretty great... it lists the records in a hierarchical (self referencing) table. The RowNumber is sweet because I can sort by id, name, whatever.

The error I get is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Code:

```
var sql = @"
WITH TREE (CategoryId, Active, Created, Modified, SortBy, [Name], [Description], Parent_CategoryId, Depth, Sort) AS
(
   SELECT 
      c.CategoryId, c.Active, c.Created, c.Modified, c.SortBy, 
      c.[Name], c.[Description], c.Parent_CategoryId, 
      0 AS Depth,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST((ROW_NUMBER() over (order by c.CategoryId)) AS VARCHAR), 10)) AS Sort 
   FROM 
      category c 
   WHERE 
      c.parent_categoryid IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
      c2.CategoryId, c2.Active, c2.Created, c2.Modified, c2.SortBy, 
      c2.[Name], c2.[Description], c2.Parent_CategoryId, 
      t.Depth + 1,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),  t.Sort + RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST((ROW_NUMBER() over (order by c2.Name)) AS VARCHAR), 10)) AS Sort
   FROM 
      Category c2
   INNER JOIN 
      TREE as t ON t.CategoryId = c2.Parent_CategoryId
)
SELECT 
    CategoryId, Active, Created, Modified, SortBy, [Name], 
    [Description], Parent_CategoryId, Depth, Sort 
FROM TREE 
WHERE depth < 2";

var result = Db.Select<Category>(sql);

--- The following is the Category object ---
namespace EdgeLib
{
    [Route("/folder", "POST")]
    public class Category
    {
        [AutoIncrement]
        [Alias("CategoryId")]
        public long? Id { get; set; }

        public bool? Active { get; set; }

        [Compute] // serialize from database... but not to database
        public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
        [Compute] // serialize from database... but not to database
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

        public double? SortBy { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Category))]
        public long? Parent_CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Index]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        // returned in the recursive query
        [Ignore]
        public int? Depth { get; set; } 
        [Ignore]
        public string Sort { get; set; } 

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "It doesn't work"? Is there an error?

Comment: Ha... sorry, pretty important tidbit I left out... I have edited the original question with this info.

Comment: Just put a semicolon `;` before the `WITH` keyword.

Comment: Then I get System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: Oh. Could you trace the SQL executed by your C# code using profiler and post it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372747/incorrect-syntax-near-works-in-sql-server-not-from-servicestack-ormlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [OrmLite's Custom SQL API's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis) when executing Custom Queries, e.g:

```
var result = Db.SqlList<Category>(sql);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had copied that statement from older code that did use custom sql... guess not! :)